# osm2pgsql style - removing amenity=school but keeping the rest of amenities

Tags: osm2pgsql

I am trying to import a PBF file using osm2pgsql, and the file looks like this:

```
...
node,way   amenity             text         polygon
# remove the school amenity data
node,way   amenity=school      text         delete
...
```

The problem is the `amenity=school` tags still make it in the database, is there a way to include all amenities but exclude the `amenity=school` tag, or should I just process it via the `SQL DELETE` statement in postgres?

I understand the `delete` flag prevents the column from being created, so this might be the reason. What are the possibilities in this use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this. By default osm2pgsql uses the C tag transforms, which use tag names to decide what data is imported. The C tag transforms do not operate on tag values, only tag names, so what your style file is saying is the tag key "amenity=school" is deleted, but it says nothing about tags with a key of amenity and a value of school.

### Postprocessing

Running some simple SQL can remove schools

`DELETE FROM planet_osm_point WHERE amenity = 'school';
DELETE FROM planet_osm_polygon WHERE amenity = 'school';`

This will remove anything that is a school. It will also remove anything that is a school as well as something else, which you may not want.

### Tag transforms

Osm2pgsql lets you specify your own tag transforms, written in Lua. You can find an example [Lua transform](https://github.com/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql/blob/master/style.lua) included with the osm2pgsql repository. This allows you to select what you want to import, but is probably overkill for the case of wanting everything except schools.

### Filtering in whatever software you are using to query

Schools don't form a significant percentage of the size of the OSM dataset. You could do a normal import, then in whatever you are using to query the database, don't select schools.

Comment: Excelent, this is what I was looking for. Thank you!